# React Native Webview get html

Tags: react-native

I want to get html in web view.
I read react-native-doc(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#content) but I cannot found it.

Can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to extract the HTML from a loaded page, or place some HTML in a webview?

Comment: I want to extract the HTML from a loaded page.

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers above worked for me, but this did. It displays the received html content of the webview in the console:

```
const jsCode = 'window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(document.documentElement.innerHTML)'

return (
            <WebView
                injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
                source={{ uri: 'https://www.whatever.com' }}
                onMessage={event => console.log('Received: ', event.nativeEvent.data)}
                javaScriptEnabled
            />
)
```

Answer (score -2):

I found this.
https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge

But I could not use this in android. This works only in android. 
I don't know this problem is only my problem or library problem.

In Android I use onNavigationStateChange. 
Read https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/586#issuecomment-90826117
I think this is not good way. But I really need this. so I used this.

Answer (score -2):

In case anyone comes across this in the future. You options here is to use javascript. You can use `injectedJavaScript` on the webview to inject a `window.postmessge($('body').html())` and then handle the reply in the `onMessage` function on the webview. The cleaner way would be to fetch the page yourself and then load it into the webview.

Comment: It doesn't work, even if the correct form is: window.postMessage(...)

Comment: Doesn't work and has typos. i.e. `window.postmessge` should be `window.postMessage`